# Как не удалять url Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы бот Телеграм, не удалял url t точка me.

Есть такой код, но он удаляет все ссылки, нужно добавить в исключение, домен Тг.

```html
def delete_links(message):
        for entity in message.entities:
            if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
                bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: Ну проверь что URL не начинается с t.me

Comment: Напишите пример кода, как прописать.